# I cannot get other Mod_Security rules triggered

Tags: apache-2.2

With Mod_Security on, only following rule is triggered.

```
--93f11d77-H--
Message: Warning. Match of "rx ^%{tx.allowed_request_content_type}$" against "TX:0" required. 
[file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/ruleset-01-crs/REQUEST-20-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "1080"] 
[id "960010"] [rev "2"] [msg "Request content type is not allowed by policy"]
```

I cannot get other Mod_Security rules triggered.
(Apache/2.9.0; OWASP_CRS/3.0.0.)

(since no browser) I have tried following, but same results.

```
curl localhost/index.html?exec=/bin/bash
curl 172.30.132.49/index.html?exec=/bin/bash
```

1. How to get other rules triggered in Mod_Security (in apache embeded in centos without browser)?
2. any CRS ruleset upgrade guidance will also be appreciated.